# Wix installer error: Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I have a wix install project converted from a msi project:

Here is the code from the Product.wxs:

```
Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="{B058DA50-08DD-442F-BAE6-70229A1C777E}" Codepage="1252" Language="1033" Manufacturer="XXX" Name="APP" UpgradeCode="{A260D180-A94B-4E81-A79B-F87EE85C054C}" Version="2.1.4">
        <Package Compressed="yes" InstallerVersion="200" Languages="1033" Manufacturer="XXX" Platform="x64" />

 <Upgrade Id="{A260D180-A94B-4E81-A79B-F87EE85C054C}">
            <UpgradeVersion Maximum="2.1.4" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" />
            <UpgradeVersion Minimum="2.1.4" Property="NEWERPRODUCTFOUND" OnlyDetect="yes" IncludeMinimum="yes" />
        </Upgrade>
```

I update the version number to 2.1.4 to 2.1.5 in the Product.wxs, rebuild the installer and run the installer on a machine already installed the 2.1.4, get a error below:

[image]

How should I resolve this error?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Change the product id, but keep the upgrade id

Comment: Make `@Product/Id="*"` to generate random GUID for every new release - defined by changing the version number. The `@Product/UpgradeCode` must be fixed. Once you increment the version and build it. During the installation setup, the old version will be removed, and the newer version will be installed.
Replace line 2, with:
`<Product Id="*" Codepage="1252" Language="1033" Manufacturer="XXX" Name="APP" UpgradeCode="{A260D180-A94B-4E81-A79B-F87EE85C054C}" Version="2.1.4">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want major upgrades.  The ProductCode has to change every build so set it to * to get the compiler to do that for you.  Also your version number much change in one of the first few versions.

MSI Defines ProductVersion as:

0-255.0-255.0-65535 rest ignored

so 1.0.1 -> 1.0.2 good. 1.0.1.2 -> 1.0.1.2 bad. You'll get duplicate entries in Add/Remove Programs.